# Is there any way to find out issue without Roku TV 5203X?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am working for roku app, client said some animation issue on **Roku TV 5203X**.  We have tested app working fine on roku stick, roku-3, roku-4 and roku premium devices but we have not Roku TV 5203X. 
Is there any way to find out issue without Roku TV 5203X? please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, there is no way you can test/debug without actual device. There is no emulator for Roku. Sorry.
If it's only animation you can disable it for that model.
Just find out what device user have with GetModel().
You can check it out here: 
[GetModel()](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifDeviceInfo#ifDeviceInfo-GetModel()asString)

Answer (score 0):

Also, be aware that the 5000 series tv models like the one you're describing have very limited texture memory and a small processor. They perform worse than the stick, and we typically use them over wifi to test our worst-case scenario to gauge the lower bounds of our channel's performance. 2DVector animations seem to do ok, but widget animations (like a rotating loading icon) are just awful.